# Polkadot v43 failed to send issue with tx pool

Tags: polkadot, substrate-parachain-template, substrate-node, transaction-pool

Zombienet + polkadot v43

two errors:

```
DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0xd7165975185efe4f63425ab930021c89f166fda20d0e4f564f61c9ebd491640e] Error importing: TooLowPriority { old: 13700, new: 513 }
```

got this error when submit tx:

```
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Subxt error:Transaction(BlockNotFound)
```

Caused by:

```
0: Transaction error: The block containing the transaction can no longer be found (perhaps it was on a non-finalized fork?)
1: The block containing the transaction can no longer be found (perhaps it was on a non-finalized fork?)
```

**The same codebase works on polkadot version 39.**

more logs with txpool

```
DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] resolve hash:0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1 finalized:false tree_route:TreeRoute { route: [HashAndNumber { number: 95, hash: 0x430087b004ca09e6dc28a11d3e61e7196b3d8c757d96b931894191ff6319f42b }, HashAndNumber { number: 96, hash: 0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1 }], pivot: 0 } best_block:0x430087b004ca09e6dc28a11d3e61e7196b3d8c757d96b931894191ff6319f42b finalized_block:0x2e32bc5184dade259838b055dc7ebc960d1431168c902fb1fdf6bdcc9ff544c5    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] handle_enactment tree_route: TreeRoute { route: [HashAndNumber { number: 95, hash: 0x430087b004ca09e6dc28a11d3e61e7196b3d8c757d96b931894191ff6319f42b }, HashAndNumber { number: 96, hash: 0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1 }], pivot: 0 }    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Pruning transactions: [0x3755cdcafff7d039c9ef3285c6e6fd5f71e53f12de9eef34231c4e0a034ad5c9, 0x54ac3158e5797fbcc5f1471ff68efe1c5bc1088066b6271020ece2916048d3fc]    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Starting pruning of block BlockId::Hash(0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1) (extrinsics: 2)    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block BlockId::Hash(0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1)    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] txpool is empty, skipping validation for block BlockId::Hash(0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1)    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Pruning at BlockId::Hash(0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1)    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #96 (0x9878…59d1)    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] Pruning at BlockId::Hash(0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1). Resubmitting transactions.    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] [0x3755cdcafff7d039c9ef3285c6e6fd5f71e53f12de9eef34231c4e0a034ad5c9] Pruned at 0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1    
2023-09-25 15:58:06.029 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [Relaychain] [0x54ac3158e5797fbcc5f1471ff68efe1c5bc1088066b6271020ece2916048d3fc] Pruned at 0x9878696aaa0eed154a7f6687e4afaff3c11cac26ca71a5bfa96870eb63d859d1
```

Comment: Did you run a migration from v39 to v43? or you just testing it on a v43 a code that worked in a v39

Comment: Migration from 39 to 43.

Comment: Probably something went wrong when you did the migration then, any more information you can share to help debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. the version subxt 0.30.0 introduced the bug.

DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker txpool: [0xd7165975185efe4f63425ab930021c89f166fda20d0e4f564f61c9ebd491640e] Error importing: TooLowPriority { old: 13700, new: 513 }

i am going to create issue in subxt repo

method next_nonce_account was removed and a new method nonce_account wokrs absolutely different way and because of it the error with nonce failed to submit tx time from time.